# Can this algebraic equation of degree 5 be solved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

I have the following algebraic equation of degree 5 which I would like to solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x) =ax^3 +bx^2 + cx + d \text{ with } a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},\; b,c,d,w,z \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$0 \stackrel{!}{=} f'(x) \cdot (f(x)-w) + x - z$$

so when you put it together gives:

$$0 \stackrel{!}{=} 3 a^2 x^5 + 5abx^4 + 2(2ac + b^2 )x^3 + 3(ad+bc-aw) x^2 + (2 b d+c^2+1-2 b w)x+(c d-c w-z)$$

I know that for arbitrary algebraic equations of degree 5 or higher there is no solution formula (Proof: Jacobson, Nathan (2009), Basic algebra 1 (2nd ed.), Dover, ISBN 978-0-486-47189-1, p. 211) But my equation seems to have a lot more structure.

So is there a solution formula for this type of equation?

### Background of this question

I'm currently trying to find out if you can calculate the points on a cubic function with shortest distance to a given point. By looking at graphs I'm sure this equation can have two solutions and it can't have 4 or more (although I don't know how to prove it).

(I'm pretty sure you can find those solutions quite well with Newtons method, but I want to know if you can directly calculate them.)

Comment: For Jacobson, just look at the references on that Wikipedia page (it is the second one).

Comment: The proof that quintics are not solvable by radicals is based on Galois theory. Pretty much must textbooks on Abstract Algebra cover Galois theory. There is also Emil Artin's book on Galois theory which is a Dover book and hence super cheap.

Comment: Degree $5$ means $x^5$ appears somewhere in the equation with a nonzero coefficient. Yours seems to be of degree $3$. Assuming that $3=5$ we can solve every equation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila now why didn't I think of setting 5 = 3.  It simplifies so much...

Comment: You can use the [Quintic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation).

Comment: This specific problem has been studied a fair bit ('closest point to spline' returns some results) and AFAIK the answer is that there is no known analytical solution.  Also, I'm less sure in the 1d case, but in the two-dimensional ($x=x(t), y=y(t)$) case you can absolutely have more than two nearest points.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: 3+(3-1)=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your quintics are still too general: Consider $f(x)=x^3$ and $[w,z]=[0,1]$. The resulting equation is $3x^5+x-1=0$ and PARI claims the Galois group of this polynomial is the full $S_5$:

```
 ? polgalois(3*x^5+x-1)
 %1 = [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
```

In fact, this is not very surprising -- the polynomial resulting from distance-minimization can be almost arbitrary. If you look at the coefficients in the fully expanded form, you'll see that $a$, $b$ and $c$ can be used to produce arbitrary coefficients at $x^5$, $x^4$ and $x^3$. The next one, $x^2$, can be controlled fully by the difference $(d-w)$, while the constant term can be adjusted arbitrarily by choice of $z$. The only one which is not arbitrary is $x$; its coefficient is determined by the preceding ones.

Comment: What is "PARI"?

Comment: PARI/GP is a free [Computer Algebra System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP).

Answer (score 0):

[Quintic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) are solvable through radicals if they meet the lengthy criteria described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics). If not, they can be solved using [Bring radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical). Either way, there's no *general* solution, as [proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) by [Abel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel#Contributions_to_mathematics) and [Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evariste_Galois) two centuries ago.

Comment: A problem of the criteria provided on Wikipedia is that there is no source (Ok, there is ISBN 3-540-43826-2, but the link is offline and it's neither available in my universities library nor at Amazon). Do you have another source for that? I don't want to do those checks just the find out later that it's wrong on Wikipedia.

Comment: A Google for [Cayley resolvent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cayley+resolvent%22) returns 300 hits, none of which, unfortunately, actually reproduce its expression (except those that merely copy the information from Wikipedia). But a search for [solvable quintic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solvable+quintic%22) and [solvable quintics](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solvable+quintics%22) returns 1,000 and 6,500 results each, where you'll find other hopefully helpful alternative expressions.